# Laravel 5 pivot tables are not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to change the home page text languages from database using Pivot tables relationship. 
All works fine and I am getting no errors but the word login is not shown.
I have 3 tables

languages

```
id  |   name    |   sign    |   default_back
1   |   English |   en      |   1
2   |   Russian |   ru      |   0
```

features

```
id  |   code    |   type    
70  |   login   |   0
```

feature_language

```
id  |   feature_id  |   language_id |   text
1   |   70          |   2           |   Ru Login
2   |   70          |   1           |   Login
```

Language Model

```
<?php // Languages Model
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Language extends Model
{
    public function features(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature');
    }
    public function getDefaulLanguage(){
        return $this->default_back;
    }
    public function featureTranslation($code){
        return $this->features()->where('code', '=', $code)->first();
    }
}
?>
```

Features Model

```
<?php  // Features Model
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Feature extends Model
{   
}
?>
```

Index controller

```
<?php // index controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers
use App\Language;
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        $languages = Language::get();
        $language_default = Language::where('default_back', '>', '0')->first();

        return view('index')->with('languages', $languages)
                            ->with('language_default', $language_default);
    }
}
?>
```

Index View

```
<?php
<h1>login : {{ $language_default->featureTranslation("login")->text}}</h1>
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated ))

Comment: I did it using the native mysql

Comment: please explain more

Comment: I used  DB::select(DB::raw(" SQL QUERY")) to pivot it using native sql queries

Comment: i see its not what i'm after, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define your pivot table column name in your model.

Language Model:

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature')->withPivot('text');
}
```

In you Index View, you need to access data like following:

```
{{ $language_default->featureTranslation("login")->pivot->text }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your pivot table has extra column `text`, you need to define the column name while defining the relationship

According to [Official Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

> By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

```
public function features(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature')->withPivot('text');
}
```

And for Retrieving the intermediate table column, you need to use the `pivot` attribute.

Comment: tried that but i got an error says "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cmslaravel.text' doesn't exist "

Comment: Oops! I think I missed the `withPivot` in  the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Language Model

```
<?php // Languages Model
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Language extends Model
{
    public function features(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature', 'feature_language', 'feature_id', 'language_id')->withPivot('text');
    }
    public function getDefaulLanguage(){
        return $this->default_back;
    }
    public function featureTranslation($code){
        return $this->features()->where('code', $code)->first()->pivot->text;
    }
}
?>
```

Index View

```
<?php
<h1>login : {{ $language_default->featureTranslation("login") }}</h1>
?>
```